# I need to validate form data from the controller without saving it in CakePHP. How to display messages below each not valid field?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-2.3

I need to validate form data from the controller without saving it in CakePHP(For search purposes). How to display messages below each not valid field the same way as id does from Model validation when you are saving the data to the database?

I know there is: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

and it works fine to determine if there is any invalid field. But how also to display a message in a standard way (like on saving data) below the invalid field and most important display it in the chosen view (I need to display it in the different view when the controller method is now)?

At the moment if data is not valid I make a redirect but how to also show there was errors at the specific fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the invalid fields using the invalidFields method. 
Your code must be something like this.

```
<?php
public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->Model->validates()) {
        // Do normal work here.
        ...
    }
    else {
        $invalidFields = $this->Model->invalidFields();
        // $invalidFields is an array with the field names as its key and
        // each value corresponds to its messages.
        // The array will look like this
        // array(
        //   'name' => array(
        //     'Invalid name', 
        //     'Must be 5-10 characters long'
        //   ),
        //   'password' => array(
        //     'Must not be empty',
        //     'Must be 8-12 characters long'
        // )     
        // You may past it then to the View.
        $this->set(array('invalidFields' => $invalidFields));
    }
}
?>
```

The on your view file

```
<form>
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <?php if (isset($invalidFields['name'])) : ?>
    <div class="error">            
        <?php // You can print all or just the first message. Its up to you. ?>
        <?php echo $invalidFields['name'][0]; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    // Other input here...
```